# R - regular expression - capturing a number in file name

Tags: regex, r

I have several files. Their name example is as follows :-

```
ABC2_5XYZ_7_data.csv     
DEF2_10QST_7_data.csv
```

Everytime when I read the filenames, I would like to capture the number beside the `_` and store them into another variable.
In the above example these are the "5" and "10".

Can anyone suggest something ?

Comment: `gsub('_(\\d+)|.', '\\1', x)` also

Comment: `gsub('.*_(\\d+).*\\.csv', '\\1', x)` also :-)

Comment: Thanks rawr and Tim. Sorry i have missed out the second occurence of the number after _. In the example is _7_. And i want to capture only the first occurence, in the example is 5 and 10. Sorry for any inconvinience.

Comment: Got it.  gsub('.*_(\\d+).*_\\d+_.*\\.csv', '\\1', x)

Answer (score 5):

I think this would work.  I added a couple more strings just to make sure.  Since we are looking for the first and only match, we can use `sub()`.

```
x <- c("ABC2_5XYZ_data.csv", "DEF2_10QST_data.csv", "A123_456ABC_data.csv", "X9F4_7912D_data.csv")
sub(".*_(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "5"    "10"   "456"  "7912"
```

The regular expression `.*_(\\d+).*` captures the digits immediately following the underscore.  The `\\1` returns us the captured digits.

- `.*` matches any character (except newline)
- `_` matches the character `_` literally
- `(` starts the capturing group
- `\\d+` match a digit one or more times
- `)` ends the capturing group
- `.*` matches any character (except newline)

Further explanation can be found at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hK1zN0/2)

**Update after OP changed the question:** In response to your comments, and the changed question, you can use the following.  Note that we are still using `sub()` (not `gsub()`!) since we want the **first match**.

```
x <- c("ABC2_5XYZ_7_data.csv", "DEF2_10QST_7_data.csv")
sub("[[:alnum:]]+_(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "5"  "10"
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. Sorry i have missed out the second occurence of the number after _. In the example is _7_.  And i want to capture only the first occurence, in the example is 5 and 10. Sorry for any inconvinience.

Comment: Got it.  gsub('.*_(\\d+).*_\\d+_.*\\.csv', '\\1', x)

Comment: `gsub()` will make it more difficult for you.  If you want the first match, use `sub()`

Comment: @Richard Scriven, your solution above returns the second ‘group’ of digits using the OPs example. ( 7 and 7  ). Something like `sub('.*_(\\d+)[A-Z].*','\\1',x)` shows the asked for numbers. ( 5 and 10)

Comment: @hvollmeier - That was before the OP changed the question.  The lower code block under **Update:** works with the edited strings.

Comment: @Richard Scriven, sorry failed to see the update :-)